# NullPointerException on Buffered Reader

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this simple bit of code causing me a headache

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Quiz.csv")));

List<String> lines = null;
String line = null;

try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.e(getLocalClassName(), e.toString());
}
```

I get a `nullPointerException` from logcat when I hit the while loop

Comment: why you create new instance of BufferedReader, but forget for the list, this is very strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lines is null. Initialise it:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed. sometimes the simple things can take the most finding!

Comment: Most popular IDEs (at least old/heavyweight ones, like NetBeans and Eclipse) can do `null` analysis, to warn you about potential problems. On eclipse, you may force a compile error for calling a method on a `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize lines like so:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
```